# Unable to load 2 angularJS components in sharepoint content editor webparts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sharepoint

I have a requirement where I need to load `2 angular components` on the same page.
First I have taken a `content editor web part` and in the HTML source, I have pasted my angular code where I'm `fetching list from SharePoint` and then displaying on the page.

My first Custom Editor web part Code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    First Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
    <br> Last Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
    <br>
    <br> Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "John";
        $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    });
</script>
```

Now, I have taken a `new custom editor web part` and almost written the `same code with just the property name changes`, but I'm unable to bind the angular to the second web part.

My second web part code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp1" ng-controller="myCtrl1"> First Name: 
   <input type="text" ng-model="firstName1"/>
   <br/> Last Name: 
   <input type="text" ng-model="lastName1"/>
   <br/> 
   <br/> Full Name: {{firstName1 + &quot; &quot; + lastName1}} </div> 
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp1', []);
app.controller('myCtrl1', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName1 = "John";
    $scope.lastName1 = "Doe";
});
</script><br/>
```

Can anyone tell me the mistake I'm doing here?
I was able to load the first component properly.
I need to load `2 components on the same page`.[image: My Output]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use 2 `ng-app` directives on the same page. This is by design.

However, you can use multiple controllers and initialize your angular component using `angular.bootstrap` method.

Modify your first webpart code as below:

```
<div id="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    First Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
    <br> Last Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
    <br>
    <br> Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
</div>
<script>

    var myfirstAppDivId = document.getElementById('myApp');
    angular.bootstrap(myfirstAppDivId, ['myApp']);
    var myfirstApp = angular.module('myApp', []);    

    myfirstApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "John";
        $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    });
</script>
```

Modify your second webpart code as below:

```
<div id="myApp1" ng-controller="myCtrl1"> First Name: 
   <input type="text" ng-model="firstName1"/>
   <br/> Last Name: 
   <input type="text" ng-model="lastName1"/>
   <br/> 
   <br/> Full Name: {{firstName1 + &quot; &quot; + lastName1}} </div> 
<script>
    var mysecondAppDivId = document.getElementById('myApp1');
    angular.bootstrap(mysecondAppDivId, ['myApp1']);
    var mysecondApp = angular.module('myApp1', []);    

    mysecondApp.controller('myCtrl1', function($scope) {
        $scope.firstName1 = "John";
        $scope.lastName1 = "Doe";
    });
</script><br/>
```

Comment: Hello @Gautam Sheth: I'm getting this error, Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error.  

Do I need to add any new script file for the bootstrapping?

Comment: No just ensure that angular js is available first and also remove duplicate angular js file references.

Comment: I have made it work using the code which I have pasted in the jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/o2mnwdq2/. the same code I have pasted in my SharePoint web part but unable to make it work. the initial binding happened and able to display the full name. but when I change the first name, nothing is happening

Comment: can you move the line `angular.bootstrap(myfirstAppDivId, ['myApp']);` after `var myfirstAppDivId = document.getElementById('myApp');` and then check ? Also ensure no duplicate angularjs files are present ? Any console errors ?

Comment: I've tried that, but I'm getting the error which I have mentioned in the first comment. So, I have googled and sorted the issue by moving it to the end. you can try that in my jsfiddle.

Comment: I have written watch expressions for both the models and made it work. please let me know if there is any other better solution for this. thanks for your help!